Problems handling tags with java and apache spark
I am new using apache spark with data bricks. I'm trying to read an xml file and process it.
My xml looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4">
<header creationtool="value" creationtoolversion="value" segtype="value" adminlang="en-us" creationid="value" srclang="en" o-tmf="value" datatype="unknown">
<prop type="defclient"> </prop>
<prop type="defproject"> </prop>
<prop type="defdomain"> </prop>
<prop type="defsubject"> </prop>
<prop type="description"> </prop>
<prop type="targetlang">fr</prop>
<prop type="name">name</prop>
</header>
<body>
<tu changedate="20170710T192020Z" creationdate="20170710T145400Z" creationid="name" changeid="name">
<prop type="client"> </prop>
<prop type="project"> </prop>
<prop type="domain"> </prop>
<prop type="subject"> </prop>
<prop type="corrected">no</prop>
<prop type="aligned">no</prop>
<prop type="x-document">document</prop>
<tuv xml:lang="en">
<prop type="value</prop>
<seg>value</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="fr">
<seg>value</seg>
</tuv>
</tu>
</body>
</tmx>

I can't handle the prop tags inside the header from those inside the body tag.
I defined the following schema and tried to separate the header tag from the body tag creating two output files
`    StructType propSchema = new StructType()
.add("_VALUE", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_type", DataTypes.StringType);
StructType header = new StructType()
.add("_creationtool", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_creationtoolversion", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_segtype", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_adminlang", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_creationid", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_srclang", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_o-tmf", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_datatype", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("prop",DataTypes.createArrayType(propSchema));

StructType segSchema = new StructType()
.add("_VALUE", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("bpt", DataTypes.createArrayType(new StructType()
.add("_i", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_type", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_VALUE", DataTypes.StringType)))
.add("ept", DataTypes.createArrayType(new StructType()
.add("_i", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_VALUE", DataTypes.StringType)));

StructType tuvSchema = new StructType()
.add("_xml:lang", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_VALUE", DataTypes.StringType, true)
.add("prop", DataTypes.createArrayType(propSchema))
.add("seg", DataTypes.createArrayType(segSchema));

StructType tuSchema = new StructType()
.add("_changedate", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_creationdate", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_creationid", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_changeid", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("prop", DataTypes.createArrayType(propSchema))
.add("tuv", DataTypes.createArrayType(tuvSchema));

StructType schema = new StructType()
.add("header", new StructType()
.add("prop", DataTypes.createArrayType(propSchema))
.add("_creationtool", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_creationtoolversion", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_segtype", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_adminlang", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_creationid", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_srclang", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_o-tmf", DataTypes.StringType)
.add("_datatype", DataTypes.StringType))
.add("body", new StructType()
.add("tu", DataTypes.createArrayType(tuSchema)));

Dataset<Row> xmlData = spark.read()
.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
.option("rowTag", "tu") 
.option("rootTag", "tmx") 
.option("declaration", "foo")
.load(inputPath);

Dataset<Row> xmlHeaderData = spark.read()
.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
.option("rowTag", "prop")
.option("rootTag", "tmx")
.option("declaration", "foo")
.schema(schema)
.load(inputPath);

xmlHeaderData.printSchema();
xmlHeaderData = xmlHeaderData.selectExpr(
"header.prop as prop");

xmlData.show(false);
xmlData.printSchema();

xmlData.write()
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
.option("rootTag", "tmx")
.option("rowTag", "tu")
.save(outputPath);
    
xmlHeaderData.write()
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
.option("rootTag", "header")
.option("rowTag", "prop")
.save(outputPath+"1");`

My first output file looks like this:
<tmx>
<tu changedate="20170710T192020Z" changeid="Myriam.Legault" creationdate="20170710T145400Z" creationid="Myriam.Legault">
<prop type="client"> </prop>
<prop type="project"> </prop>
<prop type="domain"> </prop>
<prop type="subject"> </prop>
<prop type="corrected">no</prop>
<prop type="aligned">no</prop>
<prop type="x-document">Y:\CHU ST Justine Centre de formulations pédiatriques\051713 ST Justine\051713-2017 06 29 Non Confid GPFC_ Annual Report.docx</prop>
<tuv lang="en">
<prop type="x-context-post">&lt;seg&gt;2016-2017 Annual Report&lt;/seg&gt;</prop>
<seg>&lt;bpt i="1" type="bold"&gt;{}&lt;/bpt&gt;&lt;ept i="1"&gt;{}&lt;/ept&gt;</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv lang="fr">
<seg>&lt;bpt i="1" type="bold"&gt;{}&lt;/bpt&gt;&lt;ept i="1"&gt;{}&lt;/ept&gt;</seg>
</tuv>
</tu>
</tmx>

My second output file looks like this:
<header>
<prop></prop>

<prop></prop>

<prop></prop>

<prop></prop>

<prop></prop>

<prop></prop>

<prop></prop>

<prop></prop>
</header>

I need to be able to write and convert tags (keeping some and modify them ) from the original to a new xml.
I'm using the following:
Java version = 1.8
Maven version = 3.8.1
Databricks
artifactId= spark-xml_2.11
version=0.10.0
Apache spark
artifactId=spark-core_2.11
version=2.4.8
Spark SQL
artifactId=spark-xml_2.11
version=0.10.0

from the first pass, there seems to be an error in line 21 <prop type="value</prop>. You also might want to check your UTF encoding.
